# C-Program crashes/ stops working after second scanf()

Tags: c, crash, printf, scanf

I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    int a;
    int b;

    /* scan first number*/
    printf("number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    /* scan second number*/
    printf("number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    int c = a + b;

    printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles successfully and I can run the Program but after the second "`scanf`" it crashed before "`printf("%d * %d = %d",a,b,c);`" even appears.
I use Visual Studio Code and the gc-compiler (gcc).

Comment: With what input does it crash? Also `int c = a + b;` is too early, because neither `a` nor `b` are initialized at this point.

Comment: `int c = a + b;` this instruction causes *undefined behaiour*. You are using variables `a`, and `b` before they are initialized. Move this stament *after* you actually read the variables.

Comment: You should add a and b after receiving their values.

Comment: Check the return value of scanf: `if (scanf("%d", &b) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "bad input for scanf\n"): exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int c = a + b;
```

you need to move this line behind

```
/* scan first number*/
printf("number 1: ");
scanf("%d", &a);

/* scan second number*/
printf("number 2: ");
scanf("%d", &b);
*insert it here*
```

you are trying to add undeclared variables. Program crashed because when u are trying to print c variable as int computer can't find it in memory. C has no value, or you can do it as so:

```
int main (void){

int a;
int b;


/* scan first number*/
printf("number 1: ");
scanf("%d", &a);

/* scan second number*/
printf("number 2: ");
scanf("%d", &b);

printf("%d + %d = %d",a,b,a+b);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried both mentioned opportunities but it still crashes.

Comment: can u tell me extencion of your main file, is it main.c or main. cpp VSC by default use cpp which means u are supposed to write in C++. If u want to run projects in C you need to create main.c

Comment: my files name ends with .c. 
When I run my program I have to start a .exe created by Visual Studio. Unfortunately, the implimented terminal does not work. Could the problem be related to that?

Comment: I think that your program is not crashing. If u are running it with f5 (debug mode) key there is no breakpoint in code and it just get through the program and ends in so quick time u cant even notice that. Use ctrl + f5 in this case program stops itself and freeze console. Now if console will disappear try add breakpoint above printf (click line above and press f9 red dot will appear on the left) now press f5 console will stop in this line after that press f10 if there is a problem in printf you will see crash rapport

Comment: No problem :) close question!